# How does the language bar (input language) impact keyboard hooks?

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard, input-language

I ran into a reproducible bug which doesn't really make sense to me. Hopefully someone knows more about the internals of keyboard input under Windows (I'm using Windows 7) and can point me in the right direction on how to solve it. As it stands now I don't really know where I should start to look.

My application creates a global keyboard hook, using the [MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor](https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) library. This was working fine for me, but I quickly received bug reports from people using different keyboard input languages. When they write letters with accents, **e.g. ë and ê, they show up as ¨¨e and ^^e respectively**. [This bug is also reported on the library's website](https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/workitem/624), but hasn't been resolved yet.

To try to reproduce the bug I set up an alternate input language 'Dutch (Belgium)' next to my existing 'English (United States)'. After some toying around I discovered the following:

**The bug doesn't occurs when the application which installs the hook has focus, and language is set to 'English (United States)'**. Writing in any other application (e.g. notepad) and using 'Dutch (Belgium)' to write the special characters work. The bug does occur when the application which installs the hook has focus, and language is set to 'Dutch (Belgium)'.

I am looking for any clue as how the two are related. Perhaps I need to introduce some extra checks in the keyboard hook library? The [source code of the keyboard hook is available on line](https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor/KeyboardHookListener.cs).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the input language is not updated in your application. Looking at the source code of the library that you are using, it seems that they use this call to get the correct keyboard layout:

```
   internal static extern uint GetKeyboardLayout( int dwLayout );
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of this method however emphasises:

> The input locale identifier is a broader concept than a keyboard
>   layout, since it can also encompass a speech-to-text converter, an
>   Input Method Editor (IME), or any other form of input. Since the
>   keyboard layout can be dynamically changed, applications that cache
>   information about the current keyboard layout should process the
>   WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE message to be informed of changes in the input
>   language.

However, based on a quick glance at the code, the library does not seem to respond to this `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` message, which might cause this behaviour

Also, here is a useful link to [an explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) how the Keyboard is handled by Windows